# Filtering the images from source folder to another folder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, image-processing

I have one folder named SOURCE.  In that folder around 10,000 images are there.  The folder containing images of various category.  For a particular category the image names are stored in a table.  Now i want to copy all the images which belongs to particular category from that folder and then copy all those images into another folder.

Say there is a table like this,

```
id  imagename
1    abc_1
2    abc_2
3    abc_3
4    abc_4
5    abc_5
```

All those images are in the same source folder.  I need to run a query to filter this category images and copy all those to another folder.  In that particular category i have around 1500 Images.  I am working in PHP & MYSQL Environment.  How to do this? Hope my question is clear.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: what is the filtering criteria

Comment: All the images in that tables are belongs to particular category.  Now i want to copy all the images which belongs to that table to a new folder from that source folder.  Hope i am Clear here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify after reading all the comments, this is what I understand: You would like to move specific image files on the file system to another folder, filtering those files by the imageNames in the database.

1. Retrieve the imageNames from the category table that you need (select imageNames from myCategory) and store the result set in a collection.
2. Iterate over the collection

   1. using the known directory structure match the file name and copy it over to the new directory. (take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Answer (score 0):

For copying from one table value to another table

```
insert into table2 values (select imagename from table1)
```

or

```
insert  into tablename2 (column names) 
values (select * from tablename1 where... );
```

Comment: Sorry.  This is not i am looking for.  This is very simple that i can do.  I want to copy all the images from source folder to another folder.  The image names are mentioned in the table. i can create a array which contains all the image name.  Then i want to copy that images to another folder for making some changes.